# IMPORTXML and xpath query in google sheets formula works, but not when using same xapth with UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

Trying to migrate several `IMPORTXML` formulas on a google sheet into an apps script function attached to the sheet for the sake of scheduling it to run daily, so that the numerous `IMPORTXML` formulas do not cause loading to hang or take very long during the day. I am finding that when using an xpath query on the target URL within the spreadsheet formula, things work fine, but when trying to use that same xpath query via apps script, I'm getting an error and not sure how.

This works:

```js
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/",A2,"/company-profile"), "/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")
```

... but this does not:

```js
function fetchAndWriteData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mysheet");
  var tickers = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); 
  var valuesColHeader = "p/cf"; 
  var xpathQuery = "/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]";

  for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
    var ticker = tickers[i][0]; // Get the value from column A (1-indexed)
    if (ticker) {
      // Construct the URL
      var url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"+ticker+"/company-profile";
      console.log(url)

      // Fetch the HTML content from the URL
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var content = response.getContentText();
      console.log(content)

      // Extract data using XPath
      var doc = XmlService.parse(content);
      var rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
      var elements = XmlService.getNamespace().getChild(rootNode, xpathQuery);

      if (elements.length > 0) {
        var extractedValue = elements[0].getValue();
        // Write the extracted value to the specified column
        var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        var valuesColIndex = headerRow[0].indexOf(valuesColHeader) + 1; // 1-indexed
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, valuesColIndex).setValue(extractedValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Throws error:

> Exception: Error on line 268: Attribute name "crossorigin" associated with an element type "link" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

... when execution hits the line `var doc = XmlService.parse(content);`

The tickers source column, A, looks like this:

[image]

What could be going on here? How can I fix this?

Would appreciate if any workaround (if such a thing were needed) allowed me to use one of the value selection queries/strings that can simply be copied from the browser inspector, since I have many other URL with Xpaths that I am trying to migrate to apps script:

[image]

Does not such apps script function or thing already exist?

Comment: Try cheerio(GAS fork) with  selectors.

Comment: Now, I noticed your question has been updated. From `Would appreciate if any workaround (if such a thing were needed) allowed me to use one of the value selection queries/strings that can simply be copied from the browser inspector, since I have many other URL with Xpaths that I am trying to migrate to apps script:`, I think that my answer was not useful for your situation. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike 1.I think the answer would be useful for future users - especially the point that `IMPORTXML` and `XmlService.parse` is not in feature-parity. 2. To clarify OP's updated question, They're asking for a direct way to get "any" element/value in the page, by just copying the Xpath of "that element" in the browser developer tools. In essence they're asking for a exact equivalent custom apps script that takes the same arguments as the inbuilt `IMPORTXML`(feature parity) and returns value. 3.Poor skill? I'm sure you could do that, if you wanted - but I think it'll cost month(s) of your time.

Comment: @Tanaike I think your answer was useful (I actually just came back to this post to look at it again as I was trying experiment with going the regex route as you suggested), just not what my exact issue was.

Comment: @TheMaster re. #2, that's not exactly what I'm asking. A simpler way to rephrase my question might be: Is there any such functions or way of doing things in apps script that could simply fetch the data from a URL in a way such that its elements are then able to be queried and selected based on any (as is '*any one of*') the types of query strings copyable from the context menu in the browser inspector as shown in the post image? (Given that the `IMPORTXML` function can do such a thing, I assumed that it would be simple in a related apps script if only one knew the right libraries).

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I understand your comment. I understand that OP wants to retrieve the value using the XPath. In my answer, I proposed a workaround because the XPath cannot be directly used in XmlService. When I saw the OP's reply, I couldn't understand the issue of my answer. So, I asked about it. When I saw the updated question, I was worried that my answer might be different from OP's expected goal. So, I removed my answer once. When I prepare the OP's expected solution, I would like to propose it.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Thank you for replying. I understand that you want to retrieve the value using the XPath. But, unfortunately, the XPath cannot be directly used for XmlService. So, I proposed a workaround for using regex and XmlService. And, unfortunately, I couldn't understand the issue of my answer from your reply. So, I asked about it. But, when I saw the updated question, I was worried that my answer might be different from your expected goal. So, I removed my answer once. Here, can I ask you about the issue of my answer again? When I can correctly understand it, I can modify my answer.

Comment: @Tanaike We're creating answers not for OP, but for the community. To quote a [popular meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/), *The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a knowledge repository of solutions to programming problems. Its mantra is "Make the Internet a better place". That means that a primary characteristic of a good question is that it is likely to be searched by someone else.* If you believe the answer would be useful for others, but not OP, I would advise against deletion of answers.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter As I already said, You're looking for *cheerio(GAS fork) with selectors.* Note that there's a copy selector button in your image.

Comment: @Tanaike You can just report your regex workaround and I'll accept that answer. It is ultimately the solution I ended up going with just for the added flexibility it provides. (Regex is always a pain for me, but not so hard when able to get query building help from things like ChatGPT).

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, was in the process of checking that out, thanks. (Ultimately ended up going with the regex workaround Tanaike posted, since there is apparently no easily analogous `IMPORTXML()` function or set of functions native in apps script).

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I understood your reply. So, I reopened my answer. And also, I added a script reflecting `Try cheerio(GAS fork) with selectors.` of your comment. I believe that both approaches might be useful for users.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Thank you for replying. From TheMaster's comment, I reopened my answer. And also, I added one more script reflecting `Try cheerio(GAS fork) with selectors.` of TheMaster's comment. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Just tried with the `cheeriogs` fork (https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs) and seems to work well for my purposes, thanks.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As an important point, in this case, it supposes that HTML data retrieved by the browser is the same as that retrieved by UrlFetchApp. (The value of the selector is the same HTML between the browser and UrlFetchApp.) In the case of the site where HTML is created by Javascript, the HTML data retrieved by the browser might be different from that retrieved by UrlFetchApp. At that time, please load the HTML by the browser with disabling Javascript. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in the current stage, unfortunately, xpath cannot be directly used for the object of XmlService. And also, I'm worried that all HTML data can be parsed by `XmlService.parse`. I think that your error message might be due to this. So, in your situation, how about using a combination of regex and XmlService? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function fetchAndWriteData2() {
  var valuesColHeader = "p/cf";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mysheet");
  var [headers, ...tickers] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var values = tickers.map(([ticker]) => {
    if (ticker) {
      var url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" + ticker + "/company-profile";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var content = response.getContentText();
        try {
          var table = content.match(/<table.*?VALUATION data table.*?>[\w\s\S]*?<\/table>/);
          if (table) {
            var xmlObj = XmlService.parse(table[0]);
            var root = xmlObj.getRootElement();
            var extractedValue = root.getChild("tbody", root.getNamespace()).getChildren()[5].getChildren()[1].getValue();
            return [extractedValue];
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
    return [null];
  });
  var column = headers.indexOf(valuesColHeader) + 1;
  sheet.getRange(2, column, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- By the way, I thought that `getValues()` and `setValues()` are used in a loop, the process cost will be high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) So, I moved `setValues` outside of the loop.

#### Modified script 2:

From `Try cheerio(GAS fork) with selectors.` of TheMaster's comment, when this is reflected in the script, it becomes as follows.

##### 1. Install library

Please install "cheerio for Google Apps Script". [Ref: GitHub repository of cheeriogs](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs) [Ref: Official document of "Add a library to your script project"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project)

##### 2. Retrieve selector value

Please retrieve it by "Copy selector" in your showing image. In this case, the following value is obtained.

```
#maincontent > div.region.region--primary > div.column.column--primary > div.group.left > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td.table__cell.w25
```

##### 3. Modified script:

```js
function fetchAndWriteData3() {
  var valuesColHeader = "p/cf";
  var selector = "#maincontent > div.region.region--primary > div.column.column--primary > div.group.left > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td.table__cell.w25";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mysheet");
  var [headers, ...tickers] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var values = tickers.map(([ticker]) => {
    if (ticker) {
      var url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" + ticker + "/company-profile";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var content = response.getContentText();
        try {
          const $ = Cheerio.load(content);
          return [$($(selector)["0"]).text()];
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
    return [null];
  });
  var column = headers.indexOf(valuesColHeader) + 1;
  sheet.getRange(2, column, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I do not know the values of `tickers`. And also, I'm worried whether I could correctly understand your expected values. So, when this modified script didn't work, can you provide the sample values? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [cheerio for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs)

Comment: I've updated the question to include a small example of what the "tickers" column looks like. However, I will note that using regex could be an issue because I have may other IMPORTXML formulas that I am trying to migrate and the way I am able to determine which xpath string to use to grab values from URLs is to use the browser inspector on the website and selecting copy > copy full Xpath.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply and your updated question, unfortunately, cannot understand the issue of my proposed answer. Can I ask you about the details of the issue of my proposed answer? I would like to correctly understand the issue of my answer.