# Alternative webscraper to =importXML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I have some issues with my importxml, I have tried to limit the amount of calls it does however when you have even more than 20 at once it starts to hang.

here is a link to a test example of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q8r22n32U6gBV7oh_sbgAYKdFsLOGwlVpTmDvfKeIQQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have changed it so that the formula does not run unless the date is older than 45 days, I also have a script that hard codes the data so that when the formula isn't running it picks from this instead.

However, as I stated earlier when you have multiple sheets all trying to do the same thing, there becomes overlap in dates and even one page refreshing starts to hang.

this is my current formula: =IMPORTXML([https://yuyu-tei.jp/buy/ygo/card/20pp/10001,"/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4",1](https://yuyu-tei.jp/buy/ygo/card/20pp/10001,%22/html/body/main/div/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/section%5B1%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/h4%22,1))

my question is, is there a way to do web scraping without having to rely on the formula? ideally automatically to the google sheet, each line has a unique url so the best scenario would be to go the the cell get the url and then do the scraping. I have tried to get some code from chatGPT for this however my coding experience is very very minimal and I have struggled to get this to work.

this is my current formula: =IMPORTXML([https://yuyu-tei.jp/buy/ygo/card/20pp/10001,"/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4",1](https://yuyu-tei.jp/buy/ygo/card/20pp/10001,%22/html/body/main/div/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/section%5B1%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/h4%22,1))

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77306461